# Can not install postgresql11 on CentOS 7.6

Tags: postgresql, centos

I'm installing PostgreSQL on CentOS 7.6, I want to install the newest version or at least PostgreSQL11

but here is the error message

```
[devops@DZBXDEV02 ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
[devops@DZBXDEV02 ~]$
[devops@DZBXDEV02 ~]$
[devops@DZBXDEV02 ~]$ sudo yum install -y https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/11/redhat/rhel-7.6-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-42.0-4.noarch.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-QGo8ON/pgdg-redhat-repo-42.0-4.noarch.rpm: pgdg-redhat-repo-42.0-4.noarch
/var/tmp/yum-root-QGo8ON/pgdg-redhat-repo-42.0-4.noarch.rpm: does not update installed package.
Error: Nothing to do
[devops@DZBXDEV02 ~]$
```

or an error like this

```
[devops@DZBXDEV02 ~]$ sudo rpm -Uvh https://yum.postgresql.org/11/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos11-11-2.noarch.rpm
Retrieving https://yum.postgresql.org/11/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos11-11-2.noarch.rpm
warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.5Sxp1O: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 442df0f8: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    /etc/redhat-release is needed by pgdg-redhat-repo-42.0-4.noarch
[devops@DZBXDEV02 ~]$
```

I google a lot, unfortunately, I can't find the answer to my question.

Comment: Hi @liaogx have you tried this solution https://serverfault.com/questions/764900/how-to-remove-this-warning-this-system-is-not-registered-to-red-hat-subscriptio - Apparently seems to me like this is the error *This system is not registered with an entitlement server.* for the first error.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, I tried it, but it turned out the same error.